# how to separate mysql cell in PHP by given symbol

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, separator

Suppose that in MySQL I have a row called "favourite_websites". If there are more then 1, then they are separated by comma ( , ).

> Example user 1 has "favourite_websites" set as "facebook.com"
>
> Example user 2 has it set as "facebook.com,google.com"
>
> Example user 3 has it set as "facebook.com, google.com"

What I need is to loop each user and then get each their website separately as

```
<a href='http://[website]'>[website]</a>
```

If there are more then 1 website in the cell then it should echo smt like this

```
<a href='http://[website]'>[website]</a>
<a href='http://[website]'>[website]</a>
```

Comment: use `preg_eplace()`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your string to array by using `explode` : [documentation](https://www.php.net/explode).

Example :

```
<?php
    $favourites = "facebook.com, google.com";
    $favourites_array = explode(',', $favourites);
    foreach($favourites as $website){
        $website = trim($website); //remove space characters
        echo '<a href="http://'.$website.'">'.$website.'</a>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First set your input element name as an array name, like myname[];

while posting the data,

```
$var1 = explode(",",$_POST['myname']);
```

now your query goes here,

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO tblname (fieldname) values ($var1)');
```

Comment: You've got it wrong, it's the other way round. He gets favorites as a string from database, and want to display them separately.